# Parsing Lines into UserInfo

Tags: java

What is the best way of parsing lines like below in Java into given user object

```
"Adam Xin" "Canada/British Columbia/Vancouver" 2.110


   public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String country;
    private String province;
    private String city;
    private Double rValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add methods to User class, then add a static method *parse* like below.

*public static User parse(String text) {*

```
//Parsing Logic
```

*}*

If *User* is a library class and you can't change it, then you can create a utility class and add the above method in it.

Below is the implementation of parse method.

```
public static User parse(String text) {
    List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(text);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        if (regexMatcher.group(1) != null) {
            matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
        } else if (regexMatcher.group(2) != null) {
            matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(2));
        } else {
            matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(matchList);
    String[] name = matchList.get(0).split(" ");
    String[] address = matchList.get(1).split("/");
    return new User(name[0], name[1], address[0], address[1], address[2], Double.parseDouble(matchList.get(2)));
}
```

Now whenever you want to parse a string and create User class, call the above defined method.

- Cheers!!

Comment: My question was more on the lines of what logic can be used to break down the String into individual class properties. In short, the parsing logic

Comment: Is the entire first line including double quotes a string?

Comment: Yes it is an entire string

Comment: @BrownTownCoder you should accept the answer if it has helped you